# alternate config file for a dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, configuration-files

I need advice, examples on how to get a dll to use a specific config file. it will not be the app.config or web.config. I am fairly new to c# so not sure how to make the dll read from a different location.

I don't have access to the main app.config.

Comment: You have access to the source code of the dll but not the `app.config`? Also in most cases, dll's do not have config files, config files are loaded by an executable.

Comment: yes, but in this case service agreements do not let us add to the app.config. therefore i need to be able to use a different config file that the dll can read. otherwise i will have to recompile the dll and redeploy with every change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET 3.5 DLL using its own config file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544263/net-3-5-dll-using-its-own-config-file)

Comment: Invoke your own loader from In the DLL directly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993546/app-config-for-dynamically-loaded-assemblies/11993677#11993677

Comment: You can check my video at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juBDM3fb-i0